# ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1-Update1, System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly > 'Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

**I get the following error, but ONLY in the production environment**.  Locally in the development environment, the application runs without issue.

Nowhere in my app am I referencing Json Version 6.0.0

**UPDATE: I can reproduce this error locally by PUBLISHING (VS2015) to local drive, and running approot/web.cmd locally.  So maybe the issue is in the publish.**

Question: How can I resolve this issue?

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load(Stream
>   stream)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider.Load()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Add(IConfigurationProvider
>   provider)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.JsonConfigurationExtensions.AddJsonFile(IConfigurationBuilder
>   configurationBuilder, String path, Boolean optional)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.WebApplication.Run(Type startupType, String[]
>   args)    at Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel.Program.Main(String[]
>   args)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime.Common.EntryPointExecutor.Execute(Assembly
>   assembly, String[] args, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)    at
>   Microsoft.Dnx.ApplicationHost.Program.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0()
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
>
> === Pre-bind state information === LOG: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed 
>   (Fully-specified) LOG: Appbase =
>   file:///C:/inetpub/_ALPHA/approot/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL Calling assembly : (Unknown).
>   === LOG: This bind starts in default load context. LOG: No application configuration file found. LOG: Using host configuration file:  LOG:
>   Using machine configuration file from
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed LOG: Fusion is
>   hosted. Check host about this assembly. LOG: Try host assembly store
>   with assembly newtonsoft.json, version=6.0.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorarchitecture=x86. LOG: Try
>   host assembly store with assembly newtonsoft.json, version=6.0.0.0,
>   culture=neutral, publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed,
>   processorarchitecture=msil. LOG: Try host assembly store with assembly
>   newtonsoft.json, version=6.0.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed. WRN: Host assembly store does not
>   contain this assembly. LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/inetpub/_ALPHA/approot/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/inetpub/_ALPHA/approot/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/inetpub/_ALPHA/approot/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/Newtonsoft.Json.EXE.
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL
>   file:///C:/inetpub/_ALPHA/approot/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.EXE.

Comment: How did you publish your app ? `Newtonsoft.Json` is used by `MVC`. If you want a quick fix, you can just download `Newtonsoft.Json NuGet pacakge` and extract it to `file:///C:/inetpub/_ALPHA/approot/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update1/bin` where `dnx` looks for it.

Comment: I'm just using VS 2015 to publish the app, and manually copying over to the production environment.  So yeah, after sleeping on the problem, that's what I came up with as a patch for the problem, but I shouldn't have to do this...  In my dev environment, I do not have to do this.  It would be nice that if Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json.JsonConfigurationProvider needs Json, it would package Json and go.

Comment: While copying the DLL into the BIN folder, that made that error go away, BUT I now get errors eslewhere saying that the JSON cannot be found :(

I'm thinking it may be something in the environment, because as I said, I can run the project in the DEV environment with no errors.

Comment: Did you try to create a package with `dnu publish` command ? I don't think `VS 2005` packages dependencies. Or run `dnu restore` to restore dependencies in the production env if you copy your `project.json`

Answer (score 0):

New [Newtonsoft.Json 9.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/9.0.1) has been released with ASP.NET Core support.

Answer (score -1):

Update:  I think this is related to a bug described here (https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/45) which has to do with the order in which projects are created inside the solution.  In this case, I started with a .NET 4.5.1 class library, then added the ASP.NET Core 1.0  WebAPI project.  For some reason, whenever I added my class library, Json.NET would get added to the project, but with a version number of 1.0.

**My solution was to start the solution over form scratch.  This time I started with the WebAPI project, then added in the class library, then referenced the class library within the WebAPI project, and it now shows Json.NET 8.0.2.**

I hope Microsoft gets this bug fixed, as you should be able to added a ASP.NET Core app to an existing solution without any issues, unfortunately this is not currently the case,